# How to scale the errorbars to the dimensions of the right y-axis in a plot with one x-axis and two y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df1` as below.

```
df1<-data.frame(Hour=c(0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21),
                n=c(18426,19345,20123,21450,23456,23510,21453,18456),
                mean=c(23.9234, 34.9456,28.9891,44.6452,47.4567,38.9483,34.9632,29.8765),
                ci=c(4.2345,6.3345,12.1345,17.3445,13.1545,12.1745,10.1945,28.2445))
df1$Hour<-as.factor(df1$Hour)
df1

  Hour     n    mean      ci
1    0 18426 23.9234  4.2345
2    3 19345 34.9456  6.3345
3    6 20123 28.9891 12.1345
4    9 21450 44.6452 17.3445
5   12 23456 47.4567 13.1545
6   15 23510 38.9483 12.1745
7   18 21453 34.9632 10.1945
8   21 18456 29.8765 28.2445
```

I created the plot that I show below after some search on the internet, with one x-axis and two y-axis. The left y-axis showing the variable `n` and the right y-axis showing the variable `mean`. The "orange" line represents the confidence interval (`ci`) for the mean (right y-axis).

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = df1$Hour, y = df1$n), stat = "identity", fill = "grey") +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = df1$Hour, y = df1$mean*494.2611, group=1 ), size = 1, color = "blue") + # 525.3868 result from the division of 23456/44.6452
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = df1$Hour, y = df1$mean*494.2611 )) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "n", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./494.2611, name = "Mean")) + 
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "darkgrey"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue")) + 
  labs(x = "Hour") +
  geom_errorbar(mapping= aes(x = df1$Hour, ymin = df1$mean*494.2611 - df1$ci, ymax = df1$mean*494.2611 + df1$ci),
                position = position_dodge(0.9),
                width = 0.4, colour = "orange", 
                alpha = 0.9, size = 0.5)
```

[image]

The problem is that the errorbars appear too small compare to the scale of the variable `mean`, and hence all look the same way. I think that the errorbars are scaled to the left y-axis.

Does anyone know where is the mistake?

Comment: If I make the Confidence Intervals `ci` bigger, they start to appear in the graph so I think their scales are associated to the dimensions of the variable `n` instead of the dimensions of the variable `mean`. I should refer in some way in the code that the `ci` has the scale of the right y-axis....

Comment: Yes it seems you have scaled everything on the y-axis to the 'n' range, in geom_errorbar you've forgotten to also scale the `ci` to the same range: `aes(x = df1$Hour, ymin = df1$mean*494.2611 - df1$ci*494.2611, ymax = df1$mean*494.2611 + df1$ci*494.2611)`

Comment: @teunbrand, thanks for replying. You were right, as so did January. But each one has shown me a different way of writing the code :)

Comment: I'd say January's way is better, it's more succint

Comment: But in your way, it is more understandable that the point is that we have to scale both the `mean` and the `ci`, and I didn't since I multiplied only the mean by the max(range(n)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your parentheses. Instead of

```
 ymin = df1$mean*494.2611 - df1$ci
```

use

```
 ymin = (df1$mean - df1$ci) * 494.2611
```

(same for ymax)

**Explanation:** dual scales in ggplot is a hack. You have to manually rescale the data to fit the primary scale. For error bars, you need ymin and ymax, and these are the values that you need to scale. But `ymin=df1$mean - df1$ci`, so you need to multiply the whole value, not just the mean.